# Python recursion - boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm still quite new to recursion and unable to figure out how to return a single boolean in my code. When left and right executes each will produce True or False, but how do i return a single boolean based on bool from left and bool from right?

```
def is_regex(s: str) -> bool:

    bar_and_nodes = []
    parentheses = []
    node = 0

    if len(s) == 1:
        return s == '0' or s == '1' or s == '2' or s == 'e'

    #omitted code

    if s[-1] == ')':

        # omitted code

        if node > len(s) // 2:
            split = s[1:-1].rsplit(s[node], 1)
            left = is_regex(split[0])
            right = is_regex(split[1]) 
        else:
            split = s[1:-1].split(s[node], 1)
            left = is_regex(split[0])
            right = is_regex(split[1])

        # want to return left and right
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `return left and right`? Assuming that something is a regex if all of its parts are regexes... Also, you can simplify that other line to `return s in '012e'`

Comment: In any recursive Python, you have to return your call of the function.

Comment: i tried putting `return left and right` under the `if node > len(s) // 2` and `else` statements but nothing gets returned

Comment: Is that branch reached at all? What is `node`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an `and` on `left` and `right` because if either `left` or `right` is not a regex, the whole thing is not a regex.